# Why is grid north so offset?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am not a GIS professional, only a casual orienteering enthusiast seeking an explanation from experts.

The plat of my property gives bearings and distances for each of the lines, as does the deed, however the bearings are wildly off from either true north or magnetic north.  It specifies that "course bearings are based on Connecticut Coordinate System (NAD 27)", and also displays an arrow showing the direction of grid north ("Connecticut Coordinate Grid North") about 20 degrees clockwise from a parallel of the edge of the page, a far cry from the degree or so I usually see for grid north.  Also unlike a USGS Topo map, there is no reference to either true or magnetic north, just the line marking grid north.

If I assume that the sheet is oriented to have true north be 'up', then the bearings start to make sense; e.g. an azimuth given as 341 on the sheet ends up being 1-2 degrees as I stand out in the yard and measure it with a sighting compass (correcting for declination).  In checking out the state plane coordinate system for CT, which I admittedly do not profess to fully understand, the correction (theta) for my longitude should only be about 20 *minutes*, and certainly not 20 degrees.

It's easy enough to just add 20 to each of the bearings, but I am interested in the how and why the surveyors would orient grid north in this way, as well as the mechanism someone would use to determine the exact grid-to-geodetic correction instead of just guesstimating from the edge of the paper.

Is there some missing information that I don't have?

Comment: This more of a *geography* question than a *geographic information systems* question, and therefore likely to be ruled *off-topic* for the "focused GIS question" database which is the purpose of GIS SE. Grid north can vary greatly depending on the projection and the location of the reference point with respect to standard or central meridians.  You'd need to provide very specific information for an answer to prove this, and that specificity would make the question even less appropriate.

Comment: I take it your distances are in feet or metres (meters)... Your 'map' is projected (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) which distorts true/magnetic north by a reasonable amount and, as I assume you're fairly far north, it would be *very* noticeable toward the edge of a zone or far away from the origin of the reference. Should you be entering these into the bearing/distance tool like the one in ArcGis you would specify the 20ish degree difference and it would work it out for you; the exact grid-to-geodetic can be ascertained with the local origin for your plan and stated reference.